# Core Data NSInvalidArgumentException Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, crash

I am getting a crash when changing a BOOL attribute of my NSManagedObject.

The code to save the object is:

```
self.detailItem.bookmark = [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES];
NSError *error = nil;
if (!    [self.detailItem.managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
{
    // Handle the error.
}
NSLog(@"%@", error);
```

And the error:

```
Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet. with userInfo (null)
2011-08-18 15:41:32.866 Codes[5260:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray or an NSSet.'
```

Comment: You need to add more code - what does your detailItem look like; is it just an NSManagedObject?

Comment: Yeah, the `detailItem` is just an NSManagedObject with a BOOL attribute called `bookmark`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WARNING: This answer is based on a guess I've made based on the error message; it might be 100% wrong!

---

The error looks like it's an incorrectly formed `NSPredicate`. You might have something like

```
NSString *name = @"Bob";
[NSPredicate predictaeWithFormat:@"ANY %K IN %@", @"name", name];
```

That looks like it might find anything where `name = 'Bob'` but it won't, it will throw an exception :(

If you're using 'IN' you need to pass an NSSet or NSArray i.e .

```
NSArray *names = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Alice", @"Bob", nil];
[NSPredicate predictaeWithFormat:@"ANY %K IN %@", @"name", names];
```

This will find anything with the name 'Bob' or 'Alice'.

If you just wanted to search for 'Bob', just do this :

```
NSString *name = @"Bob";
[NSPredicate predictaeWithFormat:@"%K == %@", @"name", name];
```

Comment: There is no predicate in this VC.  However I have separate VC that has this predicate `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY bookmark == YES"];` Is there anything wrong there?

Comment: The error implies that it's some other object that's interested in changes to your managed object that's causing the exception so it might be that predicate. Try it without the 'ANY' and see what happens?

Comment: Tried that but still have a crash.  For the VC we are working with, thats all the code I have related to the object, the object is pushed from parent view.  I don't have any MOC code because the object should pull the MOC itself.

Comment: It is the predicate because `"ANY bookmark == YES"` is invalid. The crash is caused by the predicate disrupting the object graph which does not become apparent until you save the context. Save errors don't have to be related to the code immediately before the save. Any errors anywhere that accumulate in the context may not be apparent until a save operation.

Comment: your assumption was correct for my case of getting the exact same error from CoreData. deleting incorrect predicate removes the crash.

Comment: Note: You should **never** use ANY and IN in the same predicate expression, it can cause crashes! The strange thing is it might work a few times and crash in others, the exact same predicate! Just finished fixing a crash bug caused exactly by using ANY and IN in the same predicate expression. Bit more clarification: ANY is used for relationships, you **should never** use it for simple attribute expression.

Comment: Do you have an example of the crashes you're getting - I've been using ANY..IN.. in live apps for a few years and got no crashes so far . . or my crash reporting is broken ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think deanWornbourne wrote the right answer, but it wasn't very clear to me so I'm going to restate his answer and insights, and provide a further explanation.

ProgramGuy was getting the serious application error because his predicate was wrong. The reason why `ANY bookmark == YES` is wrong is that "ANY" is only used where you have a one-to-many relationship in your model. When you have a one-to-one relationship, you should use `bookmark == YES`.

The 'serious application error' is a bit silly sounding and causes more alarm than necessary. However, it gives you a pretty good clue to the error. It says there is a 'bug within an observer..'. That means you have some '`NSFetchedResults`' object or '`NSFetchedResultsController`' setup (since we're talking about the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectChangedNotification`). Also, the error message says `left hand side for an ALL or ANY operator must be either an NSArray`... This is hinting that there must be a one-to-many relationship.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI.  deanWombourne's answer was 100% correct in my case.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyTeamSchedule" inManagedObjectContext:[[MyTeamStore sharedStore] context]];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY myteam.teamname == %@", myTeamName];
```

After removing the ANY the problem was solved. Thank god for dean!  Just saved me from many hours of troubleshooting and headaches.